# Show Html text in React without line breaking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Html text and want to show it in a div like below

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: THETEXT }} />
```

It shows in one line without any breaking, what should I do for showing in correct way with line breaking?

**Html Text:**

```
<p><span style="color: rgb(26, 26, 27);">&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;for&nbsp;a</span></p>
```

Now show like this:
[image]

I want to show like this (means have line breaking)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "correct way"? How "incorrect" is your current outcome?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots to better understanding the problem?

Comment: @J-007  I edited the question

Comment: Do you mean you have constrained the text in certain width but the text overflow?

Comment: you might be missing the word wrapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this line to your CSS

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS white-space.

```html
<p style="white-space: nowrap">I'm a big long line that won't wrap. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>

<p>I'm a big long line that wraps. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with this style

Comment: I have no idea what that means.